# Looking for a portable SOAP Client C++ Library

Tags: c++, web-services, soap

I'am going to have to interact with a SOAP web service, using a C++ application.

I am looking for a library that could help me do that, knowing that there's a few requirement I need to full fill:

- It needs to be portable (Windows/Linux)
- It needs to be free and open source (but I don't need to sell/distribute my code)
- It needs to support asynchronous handling of requests
- It needs to be able to support concurrent request to the server, as I will have to manage a pool of requests
- It needs to be easy to integrate

As I am not going to have a lot of different type of interactions with the server, I first thought I could just create a nice wrapper around libcurl that will let me connect to the web service. But I was wondering if parsing the reply and serializing SOAP request was not going to be complicated in this case. Using this method, I will be able to manage myself my pool of request, which is a good thing for what I want to do.

So probably I just need a library that makes it easy to parse SOAP request.

The question is, what would you consider doing ? Is there a good SOAP web client library that I could use, or should I do it myself ?

Comment: have you looked at `gsoap`? I don't know if it answers **all** your requirements, but I think it is worth looking at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the library that comes to mind to handle SOAP in C++ is [gsoap](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/) I think it matches your requirements. If I remember correctly some of their tools are not open-sourced if you use them to produce non open-source code. Check the license ...

Great toolkit. Worked very well for me some times ago ...

my2c

EDIT: As said in comment you have tools to generate code from WSDL description. That's those tools that you can not use if you do not want your code to be GPL'ed ^^

Comment: +1, a key feature that isn't mentioned yet here is that gsoap will do all the serialization and deserialization work for you, generating code from the WSDL.

Comment: I had a look at the documentation it looks like it is what I need

Comment: @jules: Yes, it is a pretty good library / set of tools. Good luck with your code